# Mobile Apps using MVC ? Can we develope?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mobile

Using Asp.net MVC 4, can we develop android mobile app and window mobile app also. visual studio 2012 is enough or i have to add some other tools, while i am searching in google i found xamarin like that any other tools or we can directly develop the mobile app with out third party tools. can you help me.

Comment: Please make your question more crisp; it's rambling.

Comment: Thank you for reply seand, My question is, can we develop mobile apps using asp.net mvc4. (android/windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer this question although I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "enough".

1) Regarding the server side, mvc4 is a great option for choosing the server side, as you communicate in rest protocol, and I chose this product as my app backend.

2) Regarding the client side, if you are already familiar with C#, then Xamarin is a wise choice for you, note that you need a license and its not cheap.
I'm using Xamarin for developing iOS & Android and although the framework is not as stable as others, I still believe  its the right choice for a C# developer, as its improving significantly over time

Comment: Hi IdoT, thanks for reply, here enough means Visual Studio 2012 is sufficient or i have to add some other third party tools to develop the mobile apps using asp.net mvc4

Comment: i want to develop the mobile app using asp.net mvc4 or mvc5.